# My privacy policy link redirects to the app on Android- Firebase Dynamic Links - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

The Privacy Policy button works correctly in debug mode on Android, but it fails to function properly in release mode. When the button is pressed within the app, it does not produce any response. Initially, I suspected that the button was completely non-functional, but I later found out that clicking on the same button in a marketing email unexpectedly redirected the user to the app instead of to the website.

My button:

```
SettingLine(
  title: context.loc.privacyPolicy,
  onTap: () async {
    launchInBrowser('https://mywebsite.com/privacy.html');
  },
  iconData: CupertinoIcons.info),
```

Releted function:

```
Future<void> launchInBrowser(String url) async {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
  if (!await launchUrl(
    uri,
    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  )) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/link/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `await`  with `async`:

```
SettingLine(
  title: context.loc.privacyPolicy,
  onTap: () async {
   await  launchInBrowser('https://mywebsite.com/privacy.html');
  },
  iconData: CupertinoIcons.info),
```

Comment: The issue is not related to 'await', and the user should not be redirected to the app when clicking on the privacy button link in the email.

Comment: so there is no problem with your button , there will be a problem in your `launchInBrowser` function

Comment: Probably there is a problem with DynamicLinks or AndroidManifest.xml I guess.